# data URI and Graphviz

Tags: svg, graphviz, data-uri

Is it possible to use the Graphviz [image] tag to embed a data URI string?
i.e.

simple.dot: (should display a red dot image -> node B)

```
digraph G {

rankdir="LR";
A -> B [label="test 1"];

A [image="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="];
B [label="foo"];

}
```

Running this with

```
dot simple.dot -o simple.svg -Tsvg
```

this is the error I'm getting

```
Warning: No such file or directory while opening data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
Warning: No or improper image="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" for node "A"
```

The resulting graph is displayed without the image in node A .

Would you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably have to modify the source of graphviz to become capable of reading/writing data uris. Presumably it needs to load the image to get the dimensions.

Another option is to not use data uris in the dot files, and instead postprocess the resulting svg (if what you wanted was a selfcontained svg file). [SVG Scour](http://www.codedread.com/scour/) might be one way to do that easily. [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) can probably also do this for you.

Comment: Yup, I've checked d graphviz source and indeed needs the dimension of the image. I guess I'll have to find another way around. Can't use Inkscase as images are created on the fly in a Webapp, and I would rather not use temp images file paths embedded in the svg. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Just filed a new feature request

Comment: @giorgioca did anything come of your feature request?

Comment: 11 years later.. is there any solution to embed images directly in graphviz `svg`?